Replace VB.NET WebBrowser control with anything other than IE11?
I'm trying to make a Windows Forms app in VB.NET with an integrated web browser, but there seems no way to do it outside of C#, with all of the libraries I've seen (Awesomium, etc.) being C and C# libraries. As I understand, the WebBrowser control is just an IE wrapper, which would be fine, were it not for IE11 being 2 years out of support with many script errors. The CSS issues aren't necessarily that big of a problem, but the security issues could be, as the app I'm dealing with uses pictures from inside the user's home. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (VB.NET), and I need a browser something the likes of Chrome or Firefox, an up-to-date browser that supports modern CSS and scripting. The basic functions (back, forward, reload) would be useful but not particularly important, with no particular access needed to page source code or console.
I'd like to keep things simple, patching WebBrowser if feasible, as it does everything I need save for the browser platform itself. The basic functions are easy to implement at the moment as well.
I've tried to use the WebBrowser control itself and messed around with its arguments (WebBrowser.something) to no avail.

WebView2
